# Between calling a script through ProcessBuilder or invoking apis directly through JNI, which is better?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, processbuilder

I have this C program that I want to call from my java code and I have 2 options :-

- Invoke a script that runs this code or
- Write a JNI layer over its apis and consume.

Which one of these approaches is preferred ? what are the pros and cons of them?

Answer (score 2):

The big advantage of running an executable via ProcessBuilder is the maximum isolation: if the child process crashes or corrupts memory, this does not effect your app. All other factors - memory utilization, performance, maintainability - are in favor of using a JNI layer over the API of the native code.

One additional consideration may be licensing. If the C program follows GPL, than the JNI approach may require open-sourcing your whole app *(I am not a lawyer, please consult a professional before jumping to conclusions in this area)*.